# How to sign an application binary, write the signature to a file and install it to rootfs in yocto build?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, digital-signature, bitbake

I have a bitbake recipe that builds a simple C hello world application and the generated application binary gets installed to the rootfs.

```
SRC_URI = "file://hello.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} hello.c ${LDFLAGS} -o hello
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/opt/project
    install -m 0755 hello ${D}/opt/project/hello
}

FILES:${PN} += "/opt/project/*"
```

I would also like to sign the `hello` binary that gets installed to the rootfs, and add that signature to the rootfs as well.

I tried extending the recipe as follows:

```
SRC_URI = "file://hello.c"
DEPENDS += "openssl-native"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} hello.c ${LDFLAGS} -o hello
}

do_sign_application() {
    openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ${PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY}/${PRIVATE_KEY_NAME}.pem -passin file:${PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY_PWD_FILE}/${PRIVATE_KEY_PWD_FILE_NAME} -out ${B}/hello.sig ${B}/hello
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/opt/project
    install -m 0755 hello ${D}/opt/project/hello
    install -m 0400 hello.sig ${D}/opt/project/hello.sig
}

addtask sign_application after do_compile before do_install

FILES:${PN} += "/opt/project/*"
```

This does indeed sign the binary created by `do_compile` and install the generated signature file to the rootfs. However, the binary created by the `do_compile` stage is different than the binary that gets deployed to the rootfs, so when I check the signature on the target it fails. It appears that some stripping and other things occur during the packaging phase that change the application binary.

How can I create the signature and install it using the correct application binary (the one that gets deployed to the rootfs)?

Comment: For starter you could try adding `INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"` to the recipe, to prevent stripping your binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. App recipe deploys it's binary after packaging and then a separate recipe handles creation and installation of signature.

Recipe for `project-app.bb`:

```
SRC_URI = "file://hello.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit deploy

do_compile() {
    ${CC} hello.c ${LDFLAGS} -o hello
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/opt/project
    install -m 0755 hello ${D}/opt/project/hello
}

do_deploy() {
    # Deploy the application for project-hello-sig to generate signature.
    install -d ${DEPLOYDIR}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/package/opt/project/hello ${DEPLOYDIR}/hello
}

addtask deploy after do_package

FILES:${PN} += "/opt/project/*"
```

Recipe for `project-app-sig.bb`:

```
DEPENDS = "openssl-native"
do_configure[depends] += "project-hello:do_deploy"

do_sign_application() {
    openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ${PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY}/${PRIVATE_KEY_NAME}.pem -passin file:${PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY_PWD_FILE}/${PRIVATE_KEY_PWD_FILE_NAME} -out ${B}/hello.sig ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/hello
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/opt/project
    install -m 0400 ${B}/hello.sig ${D}/opt/project/hello.sig
}

addtask sign_application after do_configure before do_install

FILES:${PN} += "/opt/project/*"
```